# Problem using the Angular proxy setup for development

Tags: angular, proxy, cors

I am trying to access an API from my local angular installation: [https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions"](https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions%22)

I find alot of posts about this on stack and other forums, eventually I try and follow angulars own guide: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server.

I cant get it to bypass the CORS policy after trying the guides about the Proxy setup.

I started with postman to verify that the credentials are okay and I get a 200 response from that.

I created an proxy.conf.json in the root directory of the app:

```json
{
    "/payments/v1/sessions": {
      "target": "https://api.playground.klarna.com",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/payments/v1/sessions": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
  }
```

My "caller.service.ts" in the app:

```
   stageUrl = "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions";
    
    private defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': "Basic UEsxMzg0NTZfZGY1OWRkMjdkMDMzOmk0bTVkRTRQenpjUDJsU20=",  
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
  
    post<T = any>(data: any): Observable<T> {
      return this.http.post(this.stageUrl, data, { headers: this.defaultHeaders }) as Observable<T>;
  }
```

And I run the application with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`.

I can't seem to find out what I am doing wrong with it all.

The console prints out the following:

[image: The console prints out the following:]

Comment: Isnt basic authorization for username/password instead of a token?

Comment: Have you just leaked your username (`PK138456_df59dd27d033`) and password (`i4m5dE4PzzcP2lSm`) in your question?

Comment: Yes @jub0bs but that is temporary information about the stage-api which is changed.